# Installing Software from a CD onto a Netbook

Tags: installation, netbook

I apologize if this question has come up before - I can't seem to find it.

Tonight my wife and I purchased a small samsung netbook and have been enjoying it for a light-weight solution around the house. My wife has a game she loves to play that was installed on her last laptop, but we'd like to put it on the netbook. The problem is, there's no cd-drive on the netbook and the game must be installed from a CD.

What other ways can I install software from a CD onto the netbook lacking a local cd-drive on the device itself? I would prefer to not have to create image files, and mount virtual drives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably try mapping network folder to a drive letter from the folder tool menu, or map with "subst" command from command prompt

Answer (score 1):

My brother found this with his EEE. His solution was to buy a external CD/DVD Drive, but that was the only real option open to him at the time

If you have a home network with another computer (i.e wireless) you could place the CD in the second computers CD/DVD drive, share the cd drive over the network and then run the installer from the shared CD. If you need instrcutions to do this let me know. It may take a little longer than normal, however, and depending on the copy-protection this may not work properly as the CD may have to be in the drive for the game to work.

What is the game, if I can ask?